# converting XLS to javascript rounding error

Tags: javascript, rounding-error, parsefloat

I am trying to convert an XLS spreadsheet to a Javascript based web page.
I'm pretty sure I'm running into some rounding errors. 
I get values of "cells" and then build functions, then use the results of those function to build additional functions. I know there is some redundancy like "o11=b5" but I did that to
more closely replicate the XLS file and make it easier to convert.

What are my options for a solution?

```
  var e17=parseFloat( $("#k_rcr").val())/100 ;
  var w16=parseFloat($("#k_nobt").val());
  var m12=e17*w16;
  var b5=parseFloat($("#k_nobt").val());
  var b6=parseFloat($("#k_asbw").val());
  var b7=parseFloat($("#k_spdb").val());
  var b8=parseFloat($("#k_ur").val())/100;
  var b9=parseFloat($("#k_bplm").val());
  var b11=b6/b7;
  var b12=b11*b8;
  var b13=b12*(b9*(52/12));
  var e5=parseFloat($("#k_dps").val());
  var b14=b13/e5;
  var m13=b14;
  var e6=parseFloat($("#k_fr").val())/100;
  var m14=m13*e6;
  var e18=parseFloat($("#k_alsr").val())/100;
  var e8=parseFloat($("#k_ba").val());
  var e9=parseFloat($("#k_pwm").val())/100;
  var m15=e18*e8*(1-e9); 
  var m16=m15*m14;
  var m17=m16*m12; 
  var e12=e8*(1-e9);
  var m18=(b5*m14*e12)-m17;
  var m19=parseFloat($("#k_wpv").val()); 
  var m20=m18*m19; 
  var o11=b5;
  var o13=b14;
  var o14=m14; 
  var o18=b5*o14*e12;
  var b17=parseFloat($("#k_wpv").val());
  var o19=b17;
  var o20=o18*o19;
  var o21=o20-m20; 
  var w12=0;
  var b20=parseFloat($("#k_tcpwp").val());
  var b21=parseFloat($("#k_vpwp").val());
  var w13=b20*m17;
  var w14=b21*m17;
  var w15=w12+w13+w14;
  var w16=b5;
  var w17=200;
  var w18=5;
  var w19=(w17*w16)+(w18*w16);
  var u15=0;
  var u19=0;
  var w20=(w15+w19)-(u15+u19); 
  var u25=0;
  var w25=0;
  var w26=u25-w25;
  var o29=w26; 
  var o21=o20-m20; 
  var m25=0;
  var o25=0; 
  var o26=m25-o25;
  var s29=w20;
  var q29=o26;
  var m29=o21;
  var k29=(m29+o29)-(q29+s29);


  $("#k_nibg").html( formatMoney( k29 ) );
  $("#k_bc").html( (m29/s29).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: Can you give us a simple example with 1) input data, 2) the result you got and 3) the result you would desire instead.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out Excel was rounding differently than expected.
If I forced the cells to 4 decimal places in Excel, it matched my web version exactly.